# How to set sampsize for random-forest on unbalanced data

Tags: r, random-forest

I want to build a species distribution model using random-forest:

My training data consists of 971 records of species presence (71)/absence (900) and three environmental variables at systematically sampled points (4*4m, random starting point).

Training data:

```
str(train)
'data.frame':   971 obs. of  4 variables:
$ presence: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ v1     : num  0.18 0.18 0.24 0.24 0.75 0.7 0.27 0 0.29 0.77 ...
$ v2   : num  10 110 19 99 97 71 64 45 54 74 ...
$ v3   : Factor w/ 3 levels "cat1","cat2",..: 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 1 2 ...
```

model:

```
model <- randomForest(presence ~ v1 + v2 + v3, data = train)
```

Because my data is unbalanced (71/900) I tried to include `sampsize=(c(71,71))` in the random-forest model. However, it causes the `Error in randomForest.default(m, y, ...) : sampsize should be of length one` - what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class/target variable is in numeric , you need to convert it into a factor using `as.factor`, The reasoning could be understand that it can't able to get the strata as it treats the column as numeric but once you change it to factor, `sampsize` will understand that you want to take values per staratum.

Also, note that the sampsize values must be equal to or less than the frequency for each category in case it is higher than the frequency. It will still throw an error of `larger than class frequency`

(I am assuming you want to perform classification here)

For example, The below **won't work**:

```
model <- randomForest(am ~ mpg + disp , data = mtcars,sampsize = c(10,10))
```

**This will work**:

```
model <- randomForest(as.factor(am) ~ mpg + disp , data = mtcars,sampsize = c(10,10))
```

From the documentation of `randomForest`

> sampsize   Size(s) of sample to draw. For classification, if sampsize
>   is a vector of the length the number of strata, then sampling is
>   stratified by strata, and the elements of sampsize indicate the
>   numbers to be drawn from the strata.